# What fields are available for firestore security rules for auth purposes

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using firestore phone number auth and want to utilize a rule that includes the phone number.  I see examples for fields like request.auth.token.email but cannot find documentation for other fields. When viewing 'users' in the console, the Identifier column shows the phone number.

Is there a phone number field in the auth token and how to I access it?

Bonus: Where is the documentation for what fields are present in the token for use in security rules.

Comment: This question is asking what the fields are rather than how to use a field as the 'duplicate' asks.  A stackoverflow search did not provide the answer.  The link provided in this answer is superior to the link provided in the other answer as well.  As such it should not be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Phone number is available in `request.auth.token.phone_number`, as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth).

Comment: That's `request.auth.token.phone_number`.